# Gaussian surface in uniform electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

In a uniform electric field. If we consider a Gaussian sphere and there is no charge inside. Then:
$$ E4\pi r^2 = \frac {q_{inside}}{\epsilon_0}$$
If $q_{inside}$ is $0$ then electric field should be $0$.
But first we assumed that there is uniform electric field. How can this be possible. Please explain.
If I have done something wrong then forgive please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flux is zero because the number of field lines entering the Gaussian surface is equal to the number of field lines leaving the surface from the other side of the sphere you considered. Seeing the problem in the vector form as flux($\phi$) = $\iint_{surface}$ $\vec E$ .d$\vec s$ we can see that the both sides of the area will cancel out each other. Therefore your flux is becoming zero, not because of the electric field inside the Gaussian surface(the electric field strength doesn't matter here inside the closed surface) because your uniform electric field is originated from another source and will definitely having some field strength at a point inside the sphere. And therefore by Gauss theorem, here the enclosed charge is zero as a consequence of the problem.

And also talking about the uniform electric field, 
In a uniform electric field, since the **field  strength does not vary**, the field lines are **parallel to each other and equally spaced**. Uniform fields are created by setting up a potential difference between two conducting plates placed at a certain distance from one another.

The electric field produced by a point charge is not uniform as the field originates radially from the point charge therefore they are not parallel to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The electric flux is not $E\,4\pi r^2$ as you have not taken account of the vector nature of the integral used yo evaluate flux $\int_{\rm surface}\vec E\cdot d\vec S$.

The radial electric field which you have used in you evaluation of flux is indeed perpendicular to the Gaussian surface and hence parallel to the normal to the area but is the electric field which would be produced by a point charge which certainly does not produce a uniform electric field.